# Definition of the Schur Functor

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, tensor-products, exterior-algebra

Definition of a Schur Functor

Eisenbud (p. 591) defines the schur functor to be a composite of two maps one of which is the map $\Delta^d: \wedge^d(M) \rightarrow T_d(M) = M^{\otimes d}$ obtained from the diagonalization map $\Delta: \wedge(M) \rightarrow \wedge(M \oplus M) = \wedge(M) \otimes \wedge(M)$ defined by $m \mapsto (m,m) \mapsto m \otimes 1 +1 \otimes m$.

I’m having a hard time understanding this map. I’m guessing this is the [embedding map](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/extmod.pdf) $\psi: \wedge(M) \rightarrow \otimes(M)$ defined by $m_1 \wedge m_2 \wedge \cdots \wedge m_n \rightarrow \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} (\operatorname{sgn} \sigma)m_{\sigma(1)} \otimes \cdots \otimes m_{\sigma(n)}$ since it seems to make sense with the examples Eisenbud gives. However, I’m not sure how this map is derived from the diagonal map.

For example,

$\psi(m \wedge n) = m \otimes n - n \otimes m$

but

$\Delta(m \wedge n) = (1 \otimes m + m \otimes 1) \wedge (1 \otimes n + n \otimes 1) = 1 \otimes (m \wedge n) + n \otimes m + m \otimes n + (m \wedge n) \otimes 1.$

Now $m \otimes n + n \otimes m \in M \otimes M$ but there is no minus sign...

[Here is the relevant page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vynBU.jpg)

Comment: Full reference please: what book? What edition? Preferrably, add the context. I cannot find this on p. 591 of the 1St edition of CA with a view.

Comment: A minus sign may appear out of Koszul's sign rule (which, as far as I recall, is often in play in Eisenbud's Commutative Algebra) when you commute $1\otimes m $ past $n\otimes 1$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I'm sorry I forgot to provide the reference. Yes it is Eisenbud's Commutative Algebra with a view toward algebraic geometry. I guess mine is the first edition since it does not say what edition it is. I can post a picture of the pages for reference.

Comment: @darij grinberg He mentions on page 582 that the tensor product in $\wedge(M) \otimes \wedge(M)$ is the "skew tensor product", not the regular one...I guess that's what you mean. I read that before in Eisenbud but apparently forgot about it. Thank you...now it seems to make more sense :)